# How to check if a proposed T-SQL object name is valid or needs to be enclosed in square brackets

Tags: sql-server, validation, t-sql, naming-conventions

My stored procedure may be passed an arbitrary string of characters `@String` as a `varchar` or a `nvarchar`, no more than 128 characters long.

The stored procedure needs to use that `@String` value as an object name, i.e. the name of a table, field, view or similar.

How can I determine if the value of `@String` as supplied is a valid object name in itself - i.e. is not a reserved word and does not contain invalid characters - or if it will require enclosure within (and escape of any contained) square brackets in order to *make* it a valid object name.

For example, "X", "Foo" and "C:\Temp\X.csv" are valid object names (yes, I've successfully used "C:\Temp\X.csv" as-is) and can be used unmodified, while "Select", "AB]C" and "1_ABC" are not valid, and would need to be changed to "[Select]", "[AB]]C]" and "[1_ABC]"

I would prefer a solution that *doesn't* simply attempt to create an object with that name and then checks to see if it worked.

Preference will be given to answers that are applicable over a wider range of SQL Server versions rather than only the latest version, and shorter, less complex code will be preferred over longer, more complex code.

As an example of the problem that led me to ask this question, my SP can be passed a `@Name`, which might be "C:\Temp\X.csv" or "ABC" or "SELECT" or whatever.  My SP then creates a table, populates it and *then* (so I don't have to use dynamic SQL) changes it's name to @Name using `sp_rename`.  I need to `QUOTENAME(@Name)` where @Name = "SELECT", but not in the other two cases, yielding (in the SSMS Object Explorer) tables "dbo.C:\Temp\X.csv", "dbo.ABC" and "dbo.SELECT".  However, I also need to check if these objects exist before I run the rest of the SP, and if I `QUOTENAME` "C:\Temp\X.csv", before I pass it as the new name to `sp_rename`, it appears in the SSMS Object Explorer as "dbo.[C:\Temp\X.csv]", and I must use `IF OBJECT_ID('[[C:\Temp\X.csv]]]') IS NOT NULL` to successfully determine that it exists, *not* `IF OBJECT_ID('[C:\Temp\X.csv]') IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: Why worry about whether it *needs* to be enclosed when you can just pass it to `QUOTENAME` and get on with the rest of your work. Sure, at times it will have added *unneccessary* brackets, but is that really a concern?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, yes, if I `QUOTENAME` "C:\Temp\X.csv" I get "[C:\Temp\X.csv]", but I need to *refer* to "[[C:\Temp\X.csv]]]" to *use* the resultant object.  If I don't `QUOTENAME` it, I can *refer* to it as "[C:\Temp\X.csv]" or "C:\Temp\X.csv".

Comment: Eh? I'm not sure what you mean by refer/use in your comment - once you've quoted the name, that's a name you can use throughout the rest of your code. You don't need to keep re-encoding the value. Perhaps if you could add a short example of your usage?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, have a look at my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `sp_rename`, the new name for the object never needs to be escaped, so just use the passed in `@Name` value.

It's true that `OBJECT_ID` might want an escaped name sometimes, but since a more direct test is available that, again, doesn't require escaping, I'd suggest using that as your test instead:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * from sys.tables where name = @Name)
...
```

(Or you can query `sys.objects` instead, up to you)

I had originally envisaged that you were using the name in dynamic SQL. In dynamic SQL contexts, I'd suggest just always escaping the name using `QUOTENAME`, rather than trying to determine if it needs escaping.

Answer (score 1):

This code may help understand when to use QUOTENAME. It is not used in sp_rename.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestObjectNames
    @Name SYSNAME
AS

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

-- Create temporary table
CREATE TABLE Temp (ID INT, Name SYSNAME);
-- Load temporary table
INSERT INTO Temp SELECT database_id, name FROM sys.databases;
-- Check existance of table
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = @Name)
    -- Rename table (Don't use QUOTENAME)
    EXEC sp_rename 'Temp', @Name;;
-- Fetch object id of new table (Use QUOTENAME)
SELECT OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(@Name)) AS NewTableID;
-- Select from table dynamically (Use QUOTENAME)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS NewTableCount FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@Name);
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
-- Drop new table dynamically (Use QUOTENAME)
SET @SQL = 'DROP TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@Name);
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
GO

EXEC TestObjectNames 'SELECT';
EXEC TestObjectNames 'C:\Temp\X.csv';
EXEC TestObjectNames 'AB]C';
EXEC TestObjectNames '1_ABC';
EXEC TestObjectNames 'ABC';
```